# GRUB makeactive command

Tags: grub

I am currently Dual booting Windows and Arch Linux with GRUB1 as the bootloader. On the Arch wiki, it tells me to add this at the end of my menu.lst

title Windows

rootnoverify (hd0,0)

makeactive #if you use Windows7 this line should be commented out

chainloader +1

I am wondering why I don't need makeactive when I am running Windows 7? Don't I need to make the Windows partition active?

Comment: if you put four spaces in front of code (in this case, your menu.lst file), it'll display much more nicely.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the Windows bootloader was significant updated (in Vista actually), and works completely differently.  Among other things, it plays much better with third-party bootloaders.